# Finding a vaule in XML using regex

Tags: xml, regex

I have a below xml

```
<ns1:Header>
<ns4:Name>Mohan</ns4:Name>
<ns4:Age>10</ns4:Age>
<ns4:Dept>CSE</ns4:Dept>
</ns1:Header>
```

I need to write a regex to find the Name from Mohan
tag. Here the namespace(ns4) may change dynamically .Please help to write a generic regex that should work in all the namespace

Comment: If there is only a regex it looks like: <[\w]{3}:Name>(\w+)</[\w]{3}:Name>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<ns\d+:Name>(.+)<
```

But do you really have to use RegEx? There are better ways, like System.Xml.XmlDocument class in .NET

Comment: Then I would even recommend the `XPathNavigator`

Answer (score 1):

binogure's solution seems right, I'd only make the namespace more general:

```
/<(\w+:Name)>(\w+)<\/\1>/
```

Or, if the namespace if optional:

```
/<((?:\w+)?Name)>(\w+)(\/\1>/
```

The name would be in the second capturing group.